# [Python]How to launch a program using Thread

Tags: python

professionals
I know how to launch a command in Linux's terminal via process, sth likes following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ifconfig -a')
```

But this is opened in process, how can I launch that in a thread instead?

I know "thread.start_new_thread", while this should call a function. Within the function, I still have to use subprocess. And this just to open a process again..

Thank you for your help.
Respectfully..

Comment: Rather than tell us about what you think the solution should be, can you explain the problem you are trying to solve.  threads are tools, not solutions.

Comment: Well, thank you TokenMacGuy first. The project I focus on is: launch a script,which starts a VM (which I do know how to realize it). Since the parent script is the master control the children script, who is also a process, I wish the children to be launched in threads instead of processes again.

Answer (score 3):

A command like `ifconfig` always runs in a separate process. There is no way to run that command within only a "thread" of your application.

Perhaps you could provide more detail about why you believe this is necessary, and we may be able to suggest a different approach. For example, if you need to capture the *output* of the `ifconfig` command, there are certainly ways of doing that within Python.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Sorry for not detailing the problem. The project I focus on right now is: script A launch several VMs that are embedded in another script. A is opened via process, VMs are also opened via process(just like subprocess.Popen('command'). However, since A is the parent who controls his children. I wish the VMs could be opened via threads rather than processes...

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling another process outside of your Python application, I think that there is no solution to make it run inside the Python interpreter.